# quartz scheduler jobs running continuously ignoring the cron schedule

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, continuous, cronexpression

I am using `spring 3.0.6` with `quartz 2.1.6` with oracle db in cluster mode, I am using all the quartz apis as I faced issues with spring supported quartz api.

I had some dependencies in my job class which were not initializing, I passed those in the Scheduler context and then it is working.

The problem is my cron expression is to run every 5 minutes `(0 0/5 * * * ?)` but it keeps on running my jobs continuously.

I have created job, trigger in spring context and then passing that to scheduler.scheduleJob method

I have no clue why it is continuously executing the jobs, Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the relavent Spring configuration XML?

Comment: I am experiencing similar problem. can you please let me know what was the fix.. and what was causing this continuous run ?

Answer (score 1):

How long does the job take?  Is it starting again before the last one finishes?

There's an example of a periodic SimpleTrigger in the documentation. This may be simpler for you than the CronTrigger:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05

Comment: Thanks much for the response. It turned out that as jobs were persisted in database, scheduler was executing the previous jobs, Issue got resolved when all jobs and triggers were cleared using scheduler.clear(). Thanks!